# Best way to plot heatmap in python from a function that takes two inputs?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have a function:

```
def theta_function(time, omega,  dt=0.01, cromer=True):
    # Create the variables to store the results
    times = np.arange(tstart, tend+dt, dt)  # Create the array of model times
    Nt = len(times)                         # Number of time-steps
    y = np.zeros(Nt)
    theta = np.zeros(Nt)
    z = np.zeros(Nt)
    gamma = np.zeros(Nt)

    # Set the initial conditions
    initial_y = 0
    initial_theta = 0.1
    initial_gamma = 0
    initial_z = 0

    y[0] = initial_y
    theta[0] = initial_theta

    gamma[0] = initial_gamma
    z[0] = initial_z

    # Loop over all of the times and integrate the model
    for n in range(Nt-1):
        # Time-step the angle/vertical displacement. If we are using 'Taylor' or 'Cromer"
        if cromer:
            value = math.exp(a * (y[n] - l*math.sin(theta[n])))
            z[n+1] = z[n] + (((-d*z[n]) - ((K/(M*a)) * ((math.exp(a * (y[n] - l*math.sin(
                theta[n])))) + (math.exp(a * (y[n] + l*math.sin(theta[n])))) - 2))) * dt)
            y[n+1] = y[n] + ((z[n+1] + (A * math.sin(omega * times[n]))) * dt)
            gamma[n+1] = gamma[n] + (((-d*gamma[n]) + ((((3*math.cos(theta[n]))/l) * (K/(M*a))) * (
                (math.exp(a * (y[n] - l*math.sin(theta[n])))) - (math.exp(a * (y[n] + l*math.sin(theta[n]))))))) * dt)
            theta[n+1] = theta[n] + (gamma[n+1] * dt)

    return theta[time]
```

That returns a value of theta (between 0 and pi/4), for a given time and omega.

I have a list of omegas:

```
omegas = np.linspace(2, 4, 100)
```

And a list of times:

```
times = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
```

Such that the same number of elements are contained in times and omegas.

What is the best way to create a 100x100 heat map, with times ranging from 0-1 on the x-axis, and omega ranging from 2-4 on the y-axis, where each square corresponds to a specific value of theta?

Comment: Are you asking how to use seaborn's heatmap function? Have you tried it?

Comment: I have not managed to find any examples where the heatmap is calculated directly from function using two arrays, most examples seem to involve an already formatted data set

Comment: You need to create 2D data by passing in the combinations of omega and time. Without an example function for theta I can't really say much more.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean, but I have edited my post to provide the full function

Comment: I can't help you without a minimal reproducible example (your code has a lot of undefined variables). And I'm not sure how you've been using your function until now since `times` is a numpy array of floats and in your function the `time` value is used as an index into `theta`, but you cannot use a float as an index.